# Undefined method `gsub' for #<URI::HTTPS:0x0000000404f3b8>

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to use Http::get request on url entered by user. In one recipe I have url "https://company.in.example.net:port/ha". This recipe prints the subnets available. User will select the subnet and give it as input. Suppose user gives "100.1.100.1" then I need to append it to existing url and perform http::get action on that. So the new url should be "https://company.in.example.net:port/ha/100.1.100.1" I have written following script.

```
url = 'https://company.in.example.net:port/ha/'
ruby_block 'run_my_template_resource' do
   action :create
   block do
     puts "Enter subnet: "
     input = gets
     url = url + input
     puts url
     uri =  URI.parse(URI.encode(url.to_s))
     r = Chef::Resource::Template.new('default',run_context)
     r.path       '/etc/app.conf'
     r.source     'app.conf.erb'
     r.cookbook   'testbook'
     r.owner      'root'
     r.group      'root'
     r.mode       00600
     r.variables({
     my_id: Chef::HTTP.new(uri).get('/',{ 'user-principal' => 
 '{"userName":"user","password":"pass"}', 'Accept' => 'application/json', 
 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
    })
     r.run_action :create
   end
 end
```

Here puts url printing correct url. When I run the recipe I am getting error `NoMethodError: undefined method`gsub' for #` Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Your URL is a `String`. When you get the error, it is an `URI`. Can't tell you more without a stacktrace, unfortunately (since the `gsub` is clearly not in the code you just pasted).

Comment: are you sure that Chef::HTTP.new expects a URI?  have you tried passing a string value?

Comment: `Chef::HTTP.new(url)` will work (the initializer expects a string there.)

Comment: @vhutchison yes. I have tried passing the url that i have declared in prgram. It is working on that. Url is string.

Comment: @Amadan I have removed the uri parsed part. Now input is the subnet string i am getting from user. I am appending it to current url. When I tried to give it to Chef::HTTP.new(url) it is giving "had an error: URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): https://company.in.example.net:port/ha/100.1.100.1".

Comment: Issue is resolved. I used url.chomp before passing it to Chef::HTTP.new(url). So basically after giving input ruby automatically adds newline character. Because of that it was causing bad url error. url.stomp removes that character. Anyways thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Using `gets` in Chef code is really weird and almost certainly incorrect. There will not be a user present most of the time chef-client is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

First of all you're getting `URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)` because what you are passing is not a semantically valid URI.

```
url = 'https://company.in.example.net:port/ha/'
```

I suspect that you didn't replace the `:port` with an actual port number.

Second, you're receiving user input without removing trailing whitespace. You should read your line as:

```
input = gets.chomp
```

Otherwise your input would have a trailing `\n`, giving you an invalid URI.

Third, if you're getting the gsub error is because Chef is probably expecting to receive a `String`, not an `URI` object. You can easily convert the URI to string like this:

```
Chef::HTTP.new(uri.to_s)
```

Comment: Yes. The error was because of not including chomp. It is fixed now. Thanks